# How to find default value of extend class method

Tags: php, pdo

i would like to define new class with extends of PDOStatement and in this child class i need override function bindColumn ([PDOStatement::bindColumn](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php)) and in this override function call parent::bindColumn(). But i can't find default value for this method. Is there way to find default value in any method which i would like to override? In source code or somewhere? **I need override more function and i would like to find any default value.** Thanks

```
class myStatement extends PDOStatement
{

    public function bindColumn ($column, &$param, $type = ?, $maxlen = ?, $driverdata = ?)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Download netbeans. It's a really amazing IDE..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason why I'm posting this as answers is that I can't post it as a comment.

```
/**
 * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.1.0, PECL pdo &gt;= 0.1.0)<br/>
 * Bind a column to a PHP variable
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php
 * @param mixed $column <p>
 * Number of the column (1-indexed) or name of the column in the result set.
 * If using the column name, be aware that the name should match the
 * case of the column, as returned by the driver.
 * </p>
 * @param mixed $param <p>
 * Name of the PHP variable to which the column will be bound.
 * </p>
 * @param int $type [optional] <p>
 * Data type of the parameter, specified by the PDO::PARAM_* constants.
 * </p>
 * @param int $maxlen [optional] <p>
 * A hint for pre-allocation.
 * </p>
 * @param mixed $driverdata [optional] <p>
 * Optional parameter(s) for the driver.
 * </p>
 * @return bool <b>TRUE</b> on success or <b>FALSE</b> on failure.
 */
public function bindColumn ($column, &$param, $type = null, $maxlen = null, $driverdata = null) {}
```

---

Get yourself a decent IDE man, it works wonders.

Comment: What kind of IDE? I Use Visual Studio because PHP is not my primary :-) Thanks

Comment: I personally use [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/). It's free for 30 days and not that expensive if you want to buy it. If money is an issue, NetBeans would be the way to go I assume. I've never used NetBeans. If you choose to use PHPStorm, look into a short tutorial about using its features, they're amazing as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of this method is:

```
public function bindColumn ($column, &$param, $type = null, $maxlen = null, $driverdata = null) {}
```

You can use modern IDE like PHPStorm for example to find the signature of any method and other useful information